# Convert a paramaterized query into a view in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, sql-view

Suppose I had the following table in SQL Server:

```
Date         ColA         ColB
1/1/2013     Val1A        Val1B
1/1/2013     Val2A        NULL
1/1/2013     Val3A        Val3B
1/2/2013     Val1A        NULL
1/2/2013     Val2A        Val4B
```

And, I'm looking to see the day-over-day changes for `ColB` - Which, in this case could look as follows:

```
Date         ColA         ColB_Today       ColB_Prev_Day
1/2/2013     Val1A        NULL             Val1B
1/2/2013     Val2A        Val4B            NULL
1/2/2013     Val3A        NULL             Val3B
```

So, to do this I created a fairly complex query (joining the table to itself) that has a single input variable and a calculated variable looking as follows:

```
DECLARE @Date Date = '1/2/2013', @PrevDay Date;
SET @PrevDay = (Select TOP 1 Date from MyTable where Date < @Date order BY Date desc);

SELECT
  @Date as 'Date',
  T1.ColA,
  T1.ColB as ColB_Today,
  T2.ColB as ColB_Prev_Day
FROM
  (SELECT * FROM MyTable where Date = @Date) T1,
 FULL OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT * FROM MyTable where Date = @PrevDay) T2
 ON
  T1.ColA = T2.ColA
```

Which is what I'm looking for.

Now, I'd like to be able to convert this into a View (with no parameters being passed) rather than this paramaterized query.

I hope that what I'm looking to do makes sense... In other words, the view would have the columns `Date`, `ColA`, `ColB_Today` & `ColB_Prev_Day` and it simply pulls the data from the table to create the same result without having to paramaterize date (simply, based upon the dates available in the table) - My biggest challenge seems to be the `Val3A` row above which has a value only for one of the 2 dates, not both...

Any thoughts???

Thanks!!

Comment: what version of SQL Server do you using?

Comment: For one, please stop using ambiguous formats like `1/2/2013`. Is that January 2nd or February 1st? Don't make us, other maintainers of the code, or SQL Server guess. Use unambiguous formats like `YYYYMMDD`.

Comment: Which date in your table would you pick to replace the input parameter?

Comment: If this is SQL Server 2012 you could use LAG to remove the join.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008 and @AaronBertrand, That's not what's in my table... That's just what I used to write the example... My table is substantially different and much more complicated... this was just my version to show what I was looking to achieve in the eaisest possible way....

Comment: Why not just use a Table-Valued Function *with* parameters?  It's basically the same thing.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - I know I could do this with a function, this is mostly me trying to learn SQL and see what can / cannot be done. Also, prehaps an even bigger reason is that I would like to create it in such a way that I have no need to declare the date and it could return this kind of table for all dates....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use something ugly like this:

```
with cte_dates as (
    select distinct [Date] from MyTable
), cte_vals as (
    select distinct ColA from MyTable
)
select
    d.[Date],
    v.ColA,
    T1.ColB as ColB_Today,
    T2.ColB as ColB_Prev_Day
from cte_dates as d
    cross join cte_vals as v
    left outer join MyTable as T1 on T1.ColA = v.ColA and T1.[Date] = d.[Date]
    outer apply (
        select top 1 TT.ColB
        from MyTable as TT
        where TT.ColA = v.ColA and TT.[Date] < d.[Date]
        order by TT.[Date] desc
    ) as T2
```

[**=> sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7631d/27)

It's hard to do better until I know more about your data. Do you have gaps between dates in your table?

Comment: WOW - that is kind of an ugly solution... But it is still kind of cool!!! To answer your question, there will be gaps between my dates and I always want to return this date 1's data against the most previous date before it in such a manner that if 1 of the 2 dates is missing a `ColA`, it simply returns a `NULL` for the `ColB` value.... I hope that makes sense, but please ask any other questions you may have... !!THANKS FOR THE REPLY!!!

Comment: try this one on your data to see if you have desired output

Comment: I think you mean `D.[Date]` where you've written `C.Date` also you get [all the dates](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7631d/27) not just the ones for the max date.

Comment: @ConradFrix I think that to get all possible dates is intended behaviour of OP question. Updated aliases, thank you

Comment: Maybe. I'm not completely sure what the OP is meant by *My biggest challenge seems to be the Val3A row above which has a value only for one of the 2 dates, not both* In any case if you want to match the desired output it's [easy enough to fix](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7631d/35)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - I am looking for the view to get all the data from the table and then the querier can limit the data set by putting in a `Where [Date]=...` clause on their query. What I meant by the comment about the `Val3A` row is that the view I tried to create gave me bad results when a value wasn't present for BOTH dates (it simply ignored those rows)

Comment: @RomanPekar, that did it! - I was working hard to integrate it into my solution since I have multiple columns to use as the check - not just a `ColA`, but I finally got it working!! - Thank you so much!! - Exactly what I was looking for!!!